# Using HTML buttons to variably point to links

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a way to use a button on my website as a trigger for a google script. The script needs to be called with an email input:

```
scripts.google.com/.../exec?[email]
```

Using a text input field that is submitted with a button seems the simplest.

Is it possible for the button's link to change to reflect the email typed into the text field?

NEW: Is there a HTML/CSS only way to do this?

Comment: HTML and CSS only, probably not. HTML describes the DOM (document object model), CSS Styles the DOM and javascript manipulates it. You are wanting to change the DOM dynamically by grabbing the value of one part of it and adding to the attribute of another.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
//get email  
<input id="mail" type"email" placeholder="en">

//sent data
  <button onclick="submit();">click to sent</button>


    <script>
    //get input data
    var email = document.getElementById("mail").value;
    //button clicked start function
    function submit(){
      window.location.href = "you'r url"+ "/"+ email;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: **NOTE** `document.getElementById(mail)` returns the email element, not the value  from it!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for the button's link to change to reflect the email typed into the text field?

Yes. You could use [oninput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/oninput) to do it live, or a lesser version of that such as onblur or onchange if it didn't need to change right as the user typed it. You could also simply go with onclick, and change it prior to submission ensuring that you return true during the click event handler.

> Are there better ways to approach this?

This would just be an opinion, there are certainly many ways to approach this, however especially given the lack of code presented, this isn't really answerable without context. One route could be to use an ajax request with [XMLHtppRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). It depends on what you need to get back.